# StringBuilder marshalling leads to PInvokeStackImbalance exception

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke

I'm trying to understand .Net marshalling and now i'm working with strings. I write an app but it doesn't work as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

C++

```
EXPORT void GetString(wchar_t **pBuff)
{
    std::wcout << "Initial string was: " << *pBuff << std::endl << "Changing its value..." << std::endl;
    *pBuff = L"Hello from C++";
}
```

C#:

```
const string DLLNAME = "CppLib.dll";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(256).Append("Hello from C#");
    GetString(ref sb);
    Console.WriteLine("String from Dll is {0}", sb);
}

[DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void GetString(ref StringBuilder pBuff);
```

but when I run it I get `PInvokeStackImbalance` exception.

Actual output is:

> Initial string was: Hello from C#
>
> Changing its value...
>
> *BANG - Exception is thrown here*

how to fix it? I tried to change `CallingConvention` - but it didn't help, of course, because I use StdCall here. But I have no more ideas.

In pure C++ this code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void GetString(wchar_t **pBuff)
{
    std::wcout << "Initial string was: " << *pBuff << std::endl << "Changing its value..." << std::endl;
    *pBuff = L"Hello from C++!";
}

int main() {
    wchar_t *pBuff = L"blablablablablablabla";
    GetString(&pBuff);
    std::wcout << pBuff;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also you _shouldn't_ **overwrite a string literals** unless you're looking for daemons.

Comment: Also, I am not a C++ expert. But if you use pointers and you change a string like that (like in your pure C++ code), it will only replace the amount of bytes you assign. So you also have a memory leak there.

Comment: What you need to do is 'delete' memory first. And then `allocate` it again with `new`. I would use std::string in your case though.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Here I made an example that uses std::string [link](https://ideone.com/kptWTo)

Comment: You should not be using `ref StringBuilder`, since that is already a reference type, and the C code is not creating a StringBuilder for you!. Just use `StringBuilder` without the ref. That said, `GetString()` is an abomination anyway, because how do you know how big the passed-in buffer is?

Comment: "C++ this code works fine". Really?

Comment: @henrik I don't believe it either. He should use std::string anyway

Comment: @KevinKal .Net marshaller do not support std::string so I can just interop with char/wchar_t strings. And I know about memory leak and other problems, but it's just a prototype. I expressly do not free any memory to be sure that it's not the cause of some side effects.

Comment: Try `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]ref StringBuilder pBuff`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or, better, change your C++ function to take a `BSTR*`.

Comment: @Henrik unfortunly, it's not a problem (but i tried it, and it didn't help), because C++ code can read this value without problem, so C# -> C++ interop is fine and marshalling was successful. Problem is with backward C++ -> C# interop, I cannot store a value in string on C++ side. It's caused by assigment operator. Because manual changing like `(*pBuff)[0] = 'O';` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 problems here.  The MDA probably just stepped in on your last attempt, the one that made you give up.  And sure, you already know why,  CallingConvention.StdCall is wrong.

You cannot use StringBuilder, it has to be passed without *ref* and is intended to allow the callee to copy the string contents in the buffer.  You need an extra argument, *bufferLength*, that ensures that the native code cannot destroy the GC heap.  Pass the Capacity value.  Use wcscpy_s() to copy the string content.

But you are returning a pointer.  That doesn't make the pinvoke marshaller very happy, it is a troublesome memory management issue.  It assumes that *somebody* has to clean up the string buffer.  When you let the marshaller do it then it will call CoTaskMemFree(), that rarely comes to a good end.

You'll have to fool it and declare the argument as `ref IntPtr` instead.  Then use Marshal.PtrToStringUni() in your C# code to retrieve the string.  Otherwise a nasty failure mode if you don't return a pointer to a string literal but allocate on the heap or dangle a wchar[] pointer.  Copying is the safe way.

Comment: Yes, I've got that i need to use wcscpy_s just before you answered. But anyway thanks, especially for last half of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the C++ function to take a `BSTR*`. Something like this (untested):

```
EXPORT void GetString(BSTR*pBuff)
{
    std::wcout << "Initial string was: " << *pBuff << std::endl << "Changing its value..." << std::endl;
    SysFreeString(*pBuff);
    *pBuff = SysAllocString(L"Hello from C++");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a final working solution (as legacy)

h:

```
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

EXPORT void __stdcall GetString(wchar_t *pBuff, int size);
```

cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>

EXPORT void __stdcall GetString(wchar_t *pBuff, int size)
{
    std::wcout << "Initial string was: " << pBuff << std::endl << "Changing its value..." << std::endl;
    const wchar_t *src = L"Hello from C++";
    wcscpy_s(pBuff, size, src);
}
```

C# side

```
class Program
{
    const string DLLNAME = "CppLib.dll";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(256).Append("Hello from C#");
        GetString(sb, sb.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine("String from Dll is {0}", sb);
    }

    [DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern void GetString(StringBuilder pBuff, int size);
}
```